# Title of short story of newly discovered color

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, childrens-novel

My daughter is trying to recall a book she read as a child in the 90's that contained a short story about a boy who dug up and discovered a new color in his backyard. Then his family has to buy a new tv so they can view the new color.

Comment: This sounds very familiar. I don't think I read it myself but I was told about it by a teacher or it was read out loud in class. Early 90s.

Comment: Possibly see also [The Colour Out of Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colour_Out_of_Space), although I don't think there are any televisions in that. Wikipedia lists [some fictional works that mention undiscovered colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_color#In_fiction), but I'm not sure any of them match either.

Answer (score 8):

Not a certainty, but this sounds like Betsy Byars' non-fantastic The Midnight Fox, where the young narrator recounts a daydream along these lines: digging up a new colour in his backyard, telling his parents, then everybody in the world seeing it on TV.

https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Midnight_Fox/8yccAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22new+colour%22+%22midnight+fox%22&pg=PT39&printsec=frontcover