# Book of short stories with a story about a boy who discovers a new color, and another about a car chase with toy cars

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

Possibly written in the '90s; not positive if it was meant for children to read or not.

One story was about a young boy who digs up a brand new color.

Another was about a car chase (or just cars driving) and it turns out that they are toy cars being played with by kids.

There was another story that *I think* was in the same book, although possibly not. Someone (a young girl) finds a ticking box in a second-hand store, and if you look in it when it stops ticking, you go mad.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you actually read this?

Comment: Similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/183021/title-of-short-story-of-newly-discovered-color

Comment: If so, part of the story about the new color is that they have to buy a new TV that can display the color.

Comment: Yes I saw the question but the answer wasn't what I was looking for sadly. Also I don't remember the television part but it definitely could be part of it

Comment: I read the book sometime around 2005